# Check Model instance against QuerySet

Tags: django, validation, django-models, django-queryset, django-managers

Is there a way to validate a Model instance against a QuerySet in Django, without hitting the database? I am defining a set of common QuerySets and using different model Managers for them and I would like a method on my Model that I can run to check if it's valid to that definition or not. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "validate against a QuerySet".

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to see if the instance would be returned if the QuerySet was executed. Basically checking all the fields on the model that are defined in the QS, without executing the query against the database.

Comment: Thats a strange question. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Aldarund I realize that it's kind of weird thing. I want to avoid having multiple definitions of the state of a Model. So I want to be able to query for an object based on the definition, but also being able to check if an already fetched Model falls under that definition.

Comment: @Aldarund Does that makes sense?